# Why is my LINQ stored procedure returning -1 instead of a proper number every time?

Tags: linq, stored-procedures, return-value

In the database I have a procedure that returns different numerical values ​​with the word RETURN.

This  procedure I use with LINQ in my application, but it always returns -1 instead of the proper number.

Example T-SQL:

```
Create PROCEDURE EmailStatus 
AS
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.sys.service_queues WHERE name = N'ExternalMailQueue' 
                  AND is_receive_enabled = 1)
      return (100)
   ELSE
      RETURN 101
END
```

Example LINQ:

```
TestXMLEntities nw = new TestXMLEntities();
var r = nw.EmailStatus();
```

Comment: Usually -1 means there was an error. You might want to verify your query.

Comment: In database procedure return 100 or 101, but LINQ -1. Moreover I wrote a procedure that returns only the number and linq also returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT 101 instead of RETURN 101. [Description](http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values)